# TFS Client for windows

Tags: windows, tfs

Im looking for a standalone TFS client for windows in a similar vein to TortoiseGit or GitHub for Windows.

My starting point is visual studio (or standalone team explorer), but im looking for something lighter. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for just a GIT client, or does it need to have the ability to use other TFS features?

Comment: @Chillie OP asked explicitly for TFS, so a Git client won't help.

Comment: My bad. I read his question as TFS as in the server not version control.